# Select K distinct numbers from set {1, 2,…, n} such that

Tags: algorithm, math, dynamic-programming, combinatorics

Given n and k  , k<=n. 
In How many ways we can select exactly ‘k’ distinct numbers from the set {1, 2,…, n} such that for each chosen number ‘a’ at-least one of ‘a-1’ , ‘a+1’ is also chosen?
A dynamic programming solution with time complexity **O(n*k)** is known.Can we do better?

Comment: n and K is given as input. we have to select exactly k distinct numbers

Comment: **If** you could prove that the time complexity is also `Ω(n*k)`, then the time complexity would be `Θ(n*k)`, which means you can't do better.

Comment: Can you show that O(nk) algorithm (some improvements may be possible)?

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/487207/how-many-ways-to-choose-k-out-of-n-numbers-with-exactly-at-least-m-consecu ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, we just have to do a bit of combinatorics.

Define a run to be a maximal subset of consecutive integers. We let r range from 1 to floor(k/2) and sum the number of subsets with r runs.

To count the number of subsets with a given number of runs r, we take (a) the number of ways to partition the run lengths times (b) the number of ways to partition the gaps between runs.

For (a), the number of ways to partition the integer k into a sum of r integers greater than or equal to 2 is ((k - 2r + (r - 1)) choose (r - 1)) by standard techniques.

For (b), the number of ways to partition the integer n - k into a sum of r + 1 integers where all are nonnegative and all but the first and last are positive is ((n - k - (r - 1) + r) choose r).

Naively, this formula requires O(k^2) arithmetic operations, but if we use the binomial coefficients for r - 1 to compute the ones for r, then the running time becomes O(k) arithmetic operations.